# Is there an upper limit to the amount of production at an industry?

Tags: openttd

Is there an upper limit to the amount of wood/ore/grain/livestock/oil/etc. produced in Open-TTD? I notice that many of my industries tend towards the same number but I'm not sure if there's an end to the amount it can produce.

I assume that, if yes, the industries that require inputs will also saturate in their output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a limit. The limit is determined by the base production value, and caps at either 2040 or 2295 per month (or 2550 if on a forest map, due to 10 production ticks instead of 8 or 9). This also depends on you having [smooth economy](http://wiki.openttd.org/Game_mechanics#Smooth_Economy_Rules) enabled.

To quote a [TTDPatch](http://wiki.openttd.org/TTDPatch) developer on the [OpenTTD Forum](http://www.tt-forums.net/viewtopic.php?p=163733&sid=2128541ce7feb1a96a454f56152123a2#p163733):

> "The base value for production is the amount the industry produces in
>   one step. Since a primary industry produces cargo 8 or 9 times a
>   month, the monthly production is 8 or 9 times this base value. For
>   example, the base value for a coal mine is 15 tons, so the monthly
>   production is 120 or 135 tons. This base value is capped at 255, so
>   the **maximum** possible monthly production for **any** industry is **2040** or
>   **2295**."

You could always [look through the source](http://svn.openttd.org/trunk/src/) if you don't believe the forum post. I'll even narrow it down to the [file](http://svn.openttd.org/trunk/src/industry_cmd.cpp) I think it would be in for you. Good luck!

I'm not entirely sure about the output of secondary and tertiary industries. In my experience their output is determined by input.